# Sizing a container to exact half the screen size in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to get a container to be exactly half the screen height[after considering the AppBar height] and half the screen width.

This is what I came up with...

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?
[image: current layout]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The best way and simplest route to this and similar problems is simply by using `FractionallySizedBox` widget ; e.g

```
FractionallySizedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    widthFactor: 0.5,
    child: Container(
    height: 100,
  ),
),
```

This widget (`FractionallySizedBox`)  lets you build up your `child` by specifying the fraction of the parent width (or height) which is available to the `child` widget. After that , by specifying the `alignment` , you can specify the manner the rest of the space would be allocated.

For more help on this widget , please visit the [offical help page of this widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html).

Answer (score 41):

If you want the container's height to be the half of the available space, you can use LayoutBuilder widget. With LayoutBuilder widget, you can know inside the builder function what the max available width and height would be. The example usage in your case would be like this:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return Container(
              height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Directly setting the width for the Container inside the Listview won't work, because the widget is automatically stretched to the full length of the screen. However, this method works...

Answer (score 21):

You can deduct `AppBar`'s height to configure `Container` size.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var appBar = AppBar();
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    body: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - appBar.preferredSize.height) / 2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You are on the right track about using MediaQuery, but your code can be a lot simpler:

```
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Ok, but this does not takes into account the height of AppBar, so the container is not exactly half in size.

Answer (score 6):

Or just simply...

```
SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,
          child: ...,
        ),
```